# What does comma operator in C do when we return an integer with two values?

Tags: c, comma-operator

I was actually returning a `float` value when I typed `,` instead of `.` but it did not give me any error. Then I tried running the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int getValue();
int main()
{
    int a = getValue();
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}

int getValue()
{
    return 2, 3;
}
```

**Now the output is 3**, that is it returned the second value. This happened two years ago and was searching for the proper answer since then.

Studying [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c) I came to know that it returns the second value after evaluating, but what does it do with the first one?

I studied the logic of the stack(how the values are pushed and pop internally) but I don't think this have anything to do with it.

Does it processes the two values or do something else?

Comment: I did mentioned the same in the description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.17, *Comma operator*

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

Now, to answer your question

> *what does it do with the first one?*

we can say, the first operand (left hand operand) is *evaluated* and the result is *discarded*.

<sup>NOTE: I mentioned the *result*, not the *effect*.</sup>

Just to clarify, in your case, you won't *notice* the effect, but you can *notice* it's effect if both the left and right hand expressions are related to the same variable. For example, let's discuss a simple exmple

```
return p=3, p+2;
```

We can break down the `return` statement like

- asign a value `3` to the variable `p` *[left hand side operator of `,`]*
- execute `p+2`, ehich generates a value of `5`. *[right hand side operator of `,`]*
- `return` the value `5` as the value of second argument *[following the clause : "the result (of `,` operator) has its (evaluation of right-operand) type and value."]*

See a [live demo](http://ideone.com/J4nCbc).

Comment: Won't the compiler optimize away the first operand because it has no impact and no use of its result?

Comment: @Eregrith Maybe, but that is not directly linked with the opearation of the `,` operator, right?

Comment: Yes, it's only compiler-dependent, and the OP should('ve) include(d) his compiler to the question, as he wanted to know "what really happens".

Comment: @Mat What? Is optimisation and removal of void useless impactless statements **not** compiler dependent?

Comment: @Eregrith: I had read only your second comment, sorry. Didn't understand you were talking about potential optimizations only and not the guaranteed behavior.

Comment: @Mat updated. Hope it should be simple to understand for all. Please review. :-)

Answer (score 2):

comma operator will evaluate from left to right and return the right most expression or value. This is equivalent to:

```
int getValue()
{
    (void)2;
    return 3;
}
```